# Are public functions and classes in App_code folder of a 'Website project' bad in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, public, asp.net-webpages

I have been working on an ASP.net project, and earlier, I had no clue about a 'Web site project' and a 'Web application project'. I thought both were the same, so I selected Web Site, and now I wish I had done elsewise to be able to use namespaces.

Anyway. now, I need to use some global functions and variables across all pages. So I figure the only way to do this is to make a class in the App_code directory and use its functions by instantiating an object where ever required. This is the only way out, right?

I noticed that I can only keep the class and its functions public, not even protected. I was just wondering if there's any security loophole in using a class that's public. Can anyone throw some color?

Thank you for the time.

Comment: You can use namespaces in the App_code folder.  You can also use protected and private methods in your classes.  Even if you could not do these things you could always create a class library, compile it and stick it in your Bin folder.  In either case, and even if you created a "Web application project" your classes would need to be instantiated unless their methods are defined as static methods.

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx) on this particular topic is actually pretty good:

> **Security with the App_Code Folder**
>
> Security issues with code in the App_Code folder are essentially the
>   same as those with code in the Bin folder—the code is compiled into an
>   assembly at runtime. A mitigating factor is that you can read the
>   source code for files in the App_Code folder. However, if you do not
>   fully understand the code, it can still represent a security risk.
>   Therefore, treat source code in the App_Code folder as you would treat
>   compiled code from the same source.

The issue of reading source code should only matter if you someone has access to your App_Code folder (which they shouldn't normally).

Answer (score 0):

Accessors (public, protected, private etc) have nothing to do with security. They determine scope.

What you have done - public methods on utility classes is very common. The .NET framework is full of them. Look at the System.IO.File class or System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex class, for instance. There is no security loophole.